# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in line 12

Tags: php

Edited: [This is the error I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puizn.png)

```
    $categoryName = $_POST['category_name'] ;
    $categoryDesc = $_POST['category_desc'] ;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO category (category_title, category_desc) VALUES ('$categoryName','$categoryDesc')";

    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
         echo 'Inserted successfully';
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'Inserted Failed';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

The error I got is Fatal error: Function name must be a string in line 12

line 12 : `$categoryName = $_POST['category_name'] ;`

[EDITED]
dbconnect.php (I am not sure that I am right or wrong because I am using virtual host, that's why my servername is my virtual host name)

```
<?php
$servername = "wp-one";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "personality_test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

html code

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                                <form role="form" action="../controller/AddCategory&Question.php?create=true" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Category Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CategoryName" name="category_name" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Category Description</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CategoryDesc" name="category_desc" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group input_fields_wrap">
                                        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:10px;">Add New Question</button>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Number" class="form-control" name="criteria[]"></div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-5"><input type="text" placeholder="Question" class="form-control" name="grade[]"></div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
```

Please help me, Thank You so much

Comment: What is line 11

Comment: Sound like the real error might be in `dbconnect.php` to me. Can you post the last few lines of that?

Comment: can you post your html code and dbconnect.php code also

Comment: To see if `dbconnect.php` is the real culprit, you could comment out line 12, and see if the next line produces an error.

Comment: Hmm... That code compiles on my machine. Can you post the entire error message perhaps?

Comment: @BenHillier I already added the screenshot on the top of the post. that blue link

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: @okante i use bracket to code php

Comment: @WeiXing I think you've sent a screenshot of the wrong tab. The message you described is in the first tab.

Comment: @WeiXing, as said in the documentation, this depends on your phpversion. use `mysqli_connect_error()`instead. `Warning

The mysqli->connect_error property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the mysqli_connect_error() function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.
`

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = new mysqli(...);
```

so you must use `$conn` instead of `$con`

```
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    {
         echo 'Inserted successfully';
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'Inserted Failed';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score -1):

whats your data type for **category_title** in database?

**Your Error in connection**

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
```

you use **$conn** and in insert file you use **$can** instead of $conn...

Comment: I don't think that could possibly be the cause. The SQL is later on in the code after a syntax error. It never gets as far as executing it.